# How to control ViewPager rotation which creates from the support.v4.app.ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

please help me.

I have the following problem.
From the fragment, which was created from getSupportFragmentManager() create ViewPager.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MyViewPager viewPager = MyViewPager.newInstance();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, viewPager);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Everything is ok. But if i rotate the screen.
Triggered onCreateActivity().

1. In the fragment from which I create ViewPager.
2. In ViewPager
3. In page(page in ViewPager is a fragment).

Questions:

1. That is how it should be? By this logic, I must retain ViewPager
   position and recreate ViewPager.
2. How to make it so that when rotating the screen called only
   onCreateActivity() from ViewPager and page. And not in
   parentFragment?

When i try create ViewPager from:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

I get the following error ..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0054 (com.jd:id/container) for fragment MyViewPager{41dcf008 #0 id=0x7f0f0054 My_FRAGMENT}
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
```

Thanks.

Comment: In your Activity do if(saveInstanceBundle == null) { add your viewpager fragment } this way it is not added on each rotation of the device. Furthermore I would call replace instead of add.

Comment: add - it is understandable. This I tested, I forgot to remove.
That is impossible to do differently? Only re-create?

Comment: Yes, we'll that is how the whole activity lifecycle works,  notice how Gmail, YouTube, SMS app, etc handles screen rotation. You can do hacks that makes it so that the app does not recreate everything, but that is really not something I would recommend.

Comment: That is, at any rotation, rotates Activity and with it FrameLayout. I understand correctly? Without hacks is impossible to turn only a fragment?

Comment: Nothing to do with framelayout. Other than that, you are correct. It has to recreate everything to determine how to draw layouts etc.